# Casting firestore "integer_value" to integer

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, count

Using the Golang Firestore 1.8 library, I'm trying to use the new-ish count() functions Google's Firestore introduced last fall. The docs don't seem to have examples yet, not that I've found, but I've cobbled together a somewhat-workable bit of code that gets me almost all the way, just short of actually producing an integer. The "result[userCountAlias]" value towards the bottom of this snippet is what I'm interested in converting to an integer, and I'm not quite sure how. I could, of course, take it as a string, split on the colon, and then parse it, but that seems ugly.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Many thanks.

```
func (s UserService) Count(labID string) (int64, error) {

    if s.DB == nil {
        return -1, customerrors.ErrDatabaseMissing
    }

    query := s.DB.
        Collection(CollectionUsers).
        Where("lab_id", "==", labID)


    userCountAlias := "userCount"

    ag := query.NewAggregationQuery()

    //result is a firestore.AggregationResult, which seems to consist of just a 
    //map[string]interface{}
    result, err := ag.WithCount(userCountAlias).Get(s.Ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    v := result[userCountAlias]//How do I cast this to an integer?
    fmt.Printf("Type = %v", v) //Prints "Type = integer_value:379"

    return -1, nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `fmt.Printf("Type = %T", v)` to find out the type of `v`.

`v` is most likely of type [firestorepb.Value](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore@v1.9.0/apiv1/firestorepb#Value). Please note that this is not available in 1.8 yet. Try to upgrade `cloud.google.com/go/firestore` to its latest version (it's 1.9 as of now).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore/apiv1/firestorepb"
)

func main() {
    var v interface{} = &firestorepb.Value{
        ValueType: &firestorepb.Value_IntegerValue{
            IntegerValue: 379,
        },
    }

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", v) // *firestorepb.Value
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", v) // integer_value:379

    if v, ok := v.(*firestorepb.Value); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", v.GetIntegerValue()) // 379
    }
}
```

The test in the official repository retrieves the value in the same way. See [TestIntegration_CountAggregationQuery](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/6de8edada13c751ded733e924174e5b46277fcc6/firestore/integration_test.go#L2023-L2033).

Comment: Thank you! Casting v to  a *firestorepb.Value, along with the  v.GetIntegerValue() call, absolutely did the trick.